# JSF 1.2 on Wildfly 8 Final - weld-core-jsf is still referencing JSF 2.2 API

Tags: java, jsf-1.2, jboss-weld, tomahawk, wildfly

I'm currently migrating a JSF-1.2 app to Wildfly 8 Final and am stuck :(

First of all, I've read many post with related issues (e.g. https://community.jboss.org/message/845006 or [Migrate JSF 1.2 Seam app to WildFly Beta 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19843066/migrate-jsf-1-2-seam-app-to-wildfly-beta-1)) but the proposed solution (excluding the weld subsystem) doesn't work for me.

**What I did:**

- I followed the multi-jsf feature tutorial [here](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/StepsToAddAnyNewJSFImplementationOrVersionToWildFly) and installed JSF 1.2 as a module for wildfly (to be exact, 3 modules).
- The next was that I added exclusions for javax.faces.api and com.sun.jsf-impl (main slots) as well as the corresponding dependencies to the 1.2 slots to my jboss-deployment-structure.xml for my war.
- Since the app is using Tomahawk and Tomahawk Sandbox which I am also deploying with my ear, I also excluded the main slots and included the 1.2 slots of both modules for these deployments.

**My problem:**

- When I try to call the initial page of the deployment (login.xhthml), I get the following error which is caused by the module 'org.jboss.as.jsf-injection' in slot 1.2

```
ERROR [request] UT005023: Exception handling request to /backoffice/login.faces: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.faces.context.FacesContext.getAttributes()Ljava/util/Map;
     [exec]     at org.jboss.weld.jsf.ConversationAwareViewHandler.getActionURL(ConversationAwareViewHandler.java:103)
     [exec]     at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.getActionURL(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:147)
     [exec]     at com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler.getActionURL(FaceletViewHandler.java:807)
     [exec]     at org.apache.myfaces.shared_tomahawk.renderkit.html.HtmlRenderer.getActionUrl(HtmlRenderer.java:77)
     [exec]     at org.apache.myfaces.custom.form.HtmlFormRenderer.getActionUrl(HtmlFormRenderer.java:45)
     [exec]     at org.apache.myfaces.shared_tomahawk.renderkit.html.HtmlFormRendererBase.encodeBegin(HtmlFormRendererBase.java:102)
     [exec]     at org.apache.myfaces.custom.form.HtmlFormRenderer.encodeBegin(HtmlFormRenderer.java:134)
     [exec]     at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeBegin(UIComponentBase.java:816)
     [exec]     at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:928)
     [exec]     at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:933)
     [exec]     at com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler.renderView(FaceletViewHandler.java:594)
     [exec]     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:110)
     [exec]     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
     [exec]     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
     [exec]     at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:266)
     [exec]     at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
     [exec]     at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:130)
     [exec]     at com.jamonapi.JAMonFilter.doFilter(JAMonFilter.java:57)
     [exec]     at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:56)
     [exec]     at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
     [exec]     at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter.doFilter(ExtensionsFilter.java:190)
     [exec]     at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:56)
     [exec]     at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
     [exec]     at org.apache.myfaces.custom.conversation.ConversationServletFilter.doFilter(ConversationServletFilter.java:78)
     [exec]     at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:56)
     [exec]     at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
     [exec]     at org.apache.myfaces.custom.requestParameterProvider.RequestParameterServletFilter.doFilter(RequestParameterServletFilter.java:66)
     [exec]     at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:56)
     [exec]     at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
     [exec]     at de.voebzvd.indra.backoffice.webapp.AvoidCachingFilter.doFilter(AvoidCachingFilter.java:53)
     [exec]     at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:56)
     [exec]     at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
     [exec]     at org.securityfilter.filter.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:188)
     [exec]     at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:56)
     [exec]     at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
     [exec]     at de.voebzvd.logging.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:44)
     [exec]     at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:56)
     [exec]     at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
     [exec]     at de.voebzvd.logging.NDCFilter.doFilter(NDCFilter.java:50)
     [exec]     at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:56)
     [exec]     at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
     [exec]     at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:85)
     [exec]     at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61)
     [exec]     at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
     [exec]     at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
     [exec]     at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25)
     [exec]     at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:113)
     [exec]     at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationCallHandler.java:52)
     [exec]     at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45)
     [exec]     at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:61)
     [exec]     at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70)
     [exec]     at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76)
     [exec]     at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25)
     [exec]     at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
     [exec]     at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25)
     [exec]     at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25)
     [exec]     at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:240)
     [exec]     at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:227)
     [exec]     at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:73)
     [exec]     at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:146)
     [exec]     at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:168)
     [exec]     at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:687)
     [exec]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
     [exec]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
     [exec]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

The error is caused by the ConversationAwareViewHandler which is contained in the jar weld-core-jsf-2.1.2.Final.jar in module org.jboss.as.jsf-injection which I also installed with the JSF 1.2 modules. This Class still references JSF 2.2 API and fails accordingly.

Excluding the weld subsystem from tomahawk and my war did also not work. I tried this:

```
<sub-deployment name="myfaces-tomahawk-core.jar">
  <exclude-subsystems>
    <subsystem name="weld" />
  </exclude-subsystems>
  <exclusions>
    <module name="javax.faces.api" slot="main" />
    <module name="com.sun.jsf-impl" slot="main" />
  </exclusions>
  <dependencies>
    <module name="com.sun.jsf-impl" slot="1.2" />
    <module name="javax.faces.api" slot="1.2" />
    <module name="org.apache.commons.beanutils" />
    <module name="org.apache.commons.lang" />
    <module name="org.apache.commons.logging" />
  </dependencies>
</sub-deployment>
<sub-deployment name="myfaces-tomahawk-sandbox.jar">
  <exclude-subsystems>
    <subsystem name="weld" />
  </exclude-subsystems>
  <exclusions>
    <module name="javax.faces.api" slot="main" />
    <module name="com.sun.jsf-impl" slot="main" />
  </exclusions>
  <dependencies>
    <module name="com.sun.jsf-impl" slot="1.2" />
    <module name="javax.faces.api" slot="1.2" />
    <module name="org.apache.commons.beanutils" />
    <module name="org.apache.commons.collections" />
    <module name="org.apache.commons.lang" />
    <module name="org.apache.commons.logging" />
  </dependencies>
</sub-deployment>
<sub-deployment name="backoffice.war">
  <exclude-subsystems>
    <subsystem name="weld" />
  </exclude-subsystems>
  <exclusions>
    <module name="javax.faces.api" slot="main" />
    <module name="com.sun.jsf-impl" slot="main" />
  </exclusions>
  <dependencies>
    <module name="com.sun.jsf-impl" slot="1.2" />
    <module name="javax.faces.api" slot="1.2" />
    <module name="net.sourceforge.jamonapi" />
    <module name="org.apache.commons.beanutils" />
    <module name="org.apache.commons.codec" />
    <module name="org.apache.commons.lang" />
    <module name="org.apache.commons.logging" />
  </dependencies>
</sub-deployment>
```

What can I do else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make it short, this problem is caused by an incompatibility of weld and JSF 1.2 that won't be fixed in future releases (see [here](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-3215)).

In my opinion there are three ways one can go:

1. Upgrade your application code to work with JSF 2.x.
2. Exclude the weld subsystem where necessary (will likely require reconfiguring the default-cdi settings of wildfly).
3. Patch the class `ConversationAwareViewHandler` appropriately to act differently in case of the old JSF API.

For me, there was only the option to patch the JSF-injection module since an application upgrade was not possible and option 2 would require a larger restructuring of the application.

Comment: Very well stated. I found out the following post (https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1273803), which shows a way of configuring weld to use JSF 1.2 slot. It worked fine in EAP 6.3.0.